# How to printk value of specific memory adrress?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I want to print 12byte from specific memory address in kernel.

Following is my hard coding.

```
void *Unique_Id = 0x5C000234;
for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
    printk("%02x ", *(uniqueId+i));
}
```

This is correct? or there are any other suggestion?

Please give me advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Converting integers to pointers without a cast will produce a compiler warning, so the initialization should be:

   ```
   void *Unique_Id = (void *)0x5C000234;
   ```
2. The kernel uses *virtual addresses* to access memory locations. The number `0x5C000234` is most likely a *physical address* of some registers in hardware I/O memory space. These need to be remapped into the kernel's virtual address space before their contents can be accessed. For hardware I/O memory, that is done by `ioremap()` or one of the `ioremap_*()` variants.  Pointers to remapped I/O memory should be tagged with `__iomem`:

   ```
   void __iomem *Unique_Id = ioremap(0x5C000234, 12);
   ```

   (The second parameter is the length of the mapping in bytes.)

   `ioremap()` will return `NULL` if it fails to map the memory, so that should be checked:

   ```
   if (Unique_Id == NULL) {
       /* Deal with the error */
   ```

   When the mapping is no longer required, `iounmap()` can be called to unmap it:

   ```
   iounmap(Unique_Id);
   ```
3. The contents of remapped I/O memory should not be accessed directly. There are specific functions for accessing 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, and (on 64-bit systems) 64-bit quantities. These are `readb()` and `writeb()` (8-bit), `readw()` and `writew()` (16-bit), `readl()` and `writel()` (32-bit), and `readq()` and `writeq()` (64-bit).  So the `for` loop to print 12 successive bytes could be written as:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
       printk("%02x ", readb(Unique_Id + i));
   }
   ```

   (Note that pointer arithmetic on a `void *` is a GCC extension, but is blessed by the Linux kernel developers.)

   There are also `memcpy_fromio()` and `memcpy_toio()` functions for copying between normal kernel memory and I/O memory, so the 12-byte ID could be copied into a 12-byte array using `memcpy_fromio()`:

   ```
   u8 id[12];
   memcpy_fromio(id, Unique_Id, 12);
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
       printk("%02x ", id[i]);
   }
   ```

   (`u8` is an unsigned 8-bit integer type defined by `#include <linux/types.h>`.)
4. The normal usage of `printk()` is to precede the format string with a "log-level" macro such as `KERN_INFO` (relying on C string literal concatenation to combine it with the format string), and to end the format string with a new-line character:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
       printk(KERN_INFO "%02x\n", id[i]);
   }
   ```

   That would split the ID over 12 lines in the kernel log.  There is a special `KERN_CONT` macro to indicate that the message is a continuation of a previous message, so the proper way to combine the `printk()` calls would be something like:

   ```
   printk(KERN_INFO "%02x ", id[0]);
   for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        printk(KERN_CONT "%02x ", id[i]);
   }
   printk(KERN_CONT, "%02x\n", id[11]);
   ```

   (It may be preferable to use `snprintf()` to construct a string in a temporary array of `char` and use a single call to `printk()` to print it all in one go.)
5. The kernel's print format string processing has special extensions where the `p` specifier for printing pointer values can be suffixed by various characters to change its behaviour. For example, the 12-byte ID could be printed by:

   ```
   u8 id[12];
   memcpy_fromio(id, Unique_Id, 12);
   printk(KERN_INFO "%12ph\n", id);
   ```

   That works for hex strings of up to 64 bytes.

   See [How to get printk format specifiers right](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-formats.html) for details of `printk` format specifiers.
6. The kernel has a `print_hex_dump()` function for printing hex dumps. The 12-byte ID could be printed as follows:

   ```
   u8 id[12];
   memcpy_fromio(id, Unique_Id, 12);
   print_hex_dump(KERN_INFO, "Unique_Id: ", DUMP_PREFIX_NONE, 12, 1, id, 12, false);
   ```

   (The parameters of `print_hex_dump()` are `level` (e.g. `KERN_INFO`), `prefix_str` (string prefixed to each line of output), `prefix_type` (one of `DUMP_PREFIX_NONE`, `DUMP_PREFIX_ADDRESS` or `DUMP_PREFIX_OFFSET`), `rowsize` (number of bytes printed per row of output), `groupsize` (number of bytes to print in each space-separated group), `buf` (pointer to data to dump), `len` (length of data to dump), `ascii` (include ASCII after the hex output if true).

Comment: I'm newbie of the kernel. This explanation is so perfect and very useful for me. I appreciate your answer.  I really learned many things from your reply.

Comment: In **3.** and **5.** the `\n` is missed.

Comment: @0andriy Thanks. I've added it to 5., but left it alone in 3. because I discuss the normal usage of `printk` in 4.

Answer (score 0):

I think since you want to print bytes so just cast the uniqueID + i to a character/unsigned character pointer

```
printk("%02x ", *((char *)(uniqueId+i)));
```

Comment: @Gerhardh, huh?! `void *` is considered as byte accessed. Of course, the answer here is not correct by other reason(s). See Ian Abbott's one for the details.